# Problem involving rhombus and its diagonals and height

Tags: geometry, triangles

If I know that one of the heights of a rhombus splits its longer diagonal in 2 segments equal to 7 and 11, how can I find the length of the base of the rhombus?

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear to me. Can you elaborate and explain what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let half of the shorter diagonal be x, the length of a side of the rhombus b, the said height be h, a known quantity according to the question.

We can setup 2 equations:-

(1) area of the rhombus by (4 times the green triangle with the unknown x) = area of the rhombus by (b * h with the unknown b)

(2) Use Pythagoras to relate 9, x and b

Eliminating x from (1) and (2), we will obtain a quadratic equation in b.

Solving it, we get the required.